# Segmentation fault whenever I tried to call specific functions

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Segmentation fault whenever I try to delete a node after a given node using the following fuction

I've searched for similar problems, the solutions say to check for NULL at the header which I've already done

```
struct node *delete_aft(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr,*nextptr;
    int x;
    printf("\nEnter the previous element of the element to be deleted ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    ptr=start;
    ptr->next=nextptr;
    while(ptr!=NULL&&ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
        if(ptr->data==x)
        {
            ptr->next=nextptr->next;
            free(nextptr);
            goto exit;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr=nextptr;
            nextptr=nextptr->next;
        }
    }
    if(ptr->next==NULL)
    printf("\n Element not found");
    exit:return start;
}
```

Comment: "*specific functions*" please be more .... well ... specific which functions.

Comment: when start == NULL what will happen here? ptr=start;
ptr->next=nextptr;

Comment: Exactly which line is causing the segmentation fault?

Comment: @alk I've tried to write a  function delete_aft(start); which traverses the linked list from header and when a given element is found, it deletes the next element of that element . The complete function is  also given in my question

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], or run the code in a debugger line by line to understand what is going wrong

Comment: @ServeLaurijssen I just kind of understood what you are saying sir, but a little more detailed explanation would really help.I'm a complete newbie for programming but while trying to write a program for linkedlist I've copied 2 functions create_list and insert_node_at_beginning exactly as in my textbook into my code but wrote 6 other functions all by myself. I could just look into the book but that wouldn't help me understand where the actual problem lies, Thank You :D

Comment: You have to provide context. What is `struct node`? How is it allocated? What is currently in `start`? How was it initialized?

Comment: Have a look at [Linus on Understanding Pointers](https://grisha.org/blog/2013/04/02/linus-on-understanding-pointers/) You will find two approaches to deleting from a linked list. (the naive approach, and the approach using a pointer-to-pointer)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you, this gave me a little idea of how pointers works

Comment: @KamilCuk Struct node contains an integer and a self referencing pointer
`stcut node{
 int data;
 struct node *next;
};`

Memory is allocated whenever I insert a newnode using malloc

`newnode=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));`

Start contains the head of the linked list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I commented the code where I have made changes.

```
struct node *delete_aft(struct node *start)
{
    struct node *ptr,*nextptr;
    int x;
    printf("\nEnter the previous element of the element to be deleted ");
    scanf("%d",&x);
    ptr = start;
    while (ptr != NULL && ptr->next != NULL)
    {
        if (ptr->data == x)
        {
            // Make temporary copy of ptr->next.
            nextptr = ptr->next;
            // Set ptr->next to the node after ptr->next, i.e. ptr->next->next.
            ptr->next = nextptr->next;
            free(nextptr);
            goto exit;
        }
        else
        {
            // Search the next node.
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
    }
    // If we reach this point, then x was not found, or x was the last node.
    if(ptr->next == NULL)
        printf("\n Element not found");
    exit:return start;
}
```